# Using timedelta to calculate delta between two ISO8601 times

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I am trying to calculate the delta between two ISO8601 formatted times.  I am interested in maintaining the 6 significant figures that are in the time standard.  I have discovered  "timedelta" function, but can not get it to work correctly.

```
a = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-05-09T18:28:55.251537', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%f%f%f%f%f')
b = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-05-09T18:51:55.251537', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%f%f%f%f%f')
```

Any thoughts as to how I can calculate the difference between these two times down to the millisecond?

EDIT:
My actual code is below:

```
command = "NAME,COMMAND,2018-05-10T18:31:30.515276"
command_lis = command.replace("/n"," ").split(",")
print("Received the following time: " + command_lis[2])
a = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat(), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
print("a is set")
b = datetime.datetime.strptime(command_lis[2], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
print("b is set")
delta = b - a
print(delta)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?  `timedelta` is a class, not a function.  You create time deltas by adding or subtracting times from each other.  IE `a - b` using your example code.  The resultant time delta will measure the amount of time between the two timestamps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the TimeDelta class.  In my code, if I try to run c = b - a it tells me that I can not do that to two strings...

Comment: Are you sure the code you're running is identical to what you have pasted here?  The format strings are broken (you should only have `%f` once at the end of the format field), but after making that change I'm able to subtract them and I get `datetime.timedelta(0, 1380)` as a result.

Comment: I edited the original post to include my actual code...  The problem is occurring when I set the "b" variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer (temporarily at least) because I need room for code formatting.  If I run the code you've provided in a python terminal everything appears to work as expected:

```
% python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Apr 25 2018, 00:29:19) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> command = "NAME,COMMAND,2018-05-10T18:31:30.515276"
>>> command_lis = command.replace("/n"," ").split(",")
>>> print("Received the following time: " + command_lis[2])
Received the following time: 2018-05-10T18:31:30.515276
>>> a = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat(), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> print("a is set")
a is set
>>> b = datetime.datetime.strptime(command_lis[2], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> print("b is set")
b is set
>>> delta = b - a
>>> print(delta)
-5 days, 18:25:54.502559
```

Are you getting different behavior?

Comment: Not too sure what the issue was.  I assume I had a typo or something along that line.  Works like a champ!  Thanks for your help